# Repeat animation only once

Tags: flutter

There's an interactive example in the flutter docs with [slide transition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html). The animations looks great but I can't stop the animation from constantly repeating. There's a `repeat` method used on the `AnimationController` that seems to control the looping of the animation. But I can't see where you can for instance run the animation twice?

Here is the code for connivence ..

/ The following code implements the [SlideTransition] as seen in the video
// above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);
  late final Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
    begin: Offset.zero,
    end: const Offset(1.5, 0.0),
  ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.elasticIn,
  ));

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FlutterLogo(size: 150.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `forward` and wait for it to resolve and then call `reverse`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    repeatOnce();
  }

  void repeatOnce() async {
    await _controller.forward();
    await _controller.reverse();
  }
```

The Full example

```
/// Flutter code sample for SlideTransition

// The following code implements the [SlideTransition] as seen in the video
// above:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  );

  late final Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
    begin: Offset.zero,
    end: const Offset(1.5, 0.0),
  ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.elasticIn,
  ));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    repeatOnce();
  }

  void repeatOnce() async {
    await _controller.forward();
    await _controller.reverse();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FlutterLogo(size: 150.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```